# Render custom radio button group with react-jsonschema-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm using react-jsonschema-form to render a form.
I can't figure out how to render a group of custom radio button elements. all I get is a single element

this is my schema:

```
overwrite: {
      type: "number",
      title: "Overwrite",
      default: 2,
      description: "Using enum",
      oneOf: [
        {
          type: "number",
          title: "One",
          enum: [1],
        },
        {
          type: "number",
          title: "2",
          enum: [2],
        },
        {
          type: "number",
          title: "Num 3",
          enum: [3],
        },
      ],
    }
```

My uiSchema:

```
      overwrite: {
        "ui:widget": "radio",
      }
```

A custom radio button:

```
    const CustomRadio = (props: WidgetProps) => {
      return (
        <>
          <RadioButton
            id={props.id}
            name={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value)}
            checked={props.defaultChecked}
            disabled={props.disabled}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
```

And finally, the form:

```
        <Form
          FieldTemplate={FormRowTemplate}
          schema={FormSchema}
          uiSchema={uiSchema}
          widgets={widgets}
        >
          <>{/* this is to hide the submit button*/}</>
        </Form>
```

Which results in a single, empty radio button:

[image]

Thanks for the help!